# It is possible to open function library in keyword view of HP UFT/QTP?

Tags: vbscript, qtp, hp-uft, uft-api, uft14

If I want to open function library in keyword view for give data parameter and any other activity then it is not possible right now.
Is there any possibility for it?

i.e. I want login part in every test case so I created this login part in function library. But now if I want to give different value using parameter of Username and Password in function library then how it is possible and Can I open it in keyword view?

Comment: A function library will contain functions - in your case, its Login. So if you want to call this function everywhere, why can't you pass the login details as function arguments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to open a function library in keyword view, because this editor is designed to add new steps only to an action.